# White border on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this [javascript](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery), which scrolls pages (divs).

The problem I am having is, when resizing the browser window. A white border appears.



[image]



Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?


**URL to my slightly modified version [here](http://pad.ample.pw/hz-scroll/horizontal.html)**.


Thanks.

Comment: The white borders, only appear when the page shrinks, and they're the size of the scroll-bars, try on resize set the coloured div to 100% width height.

Comment: @Kiee The coloured div is set to 100% already. Overflow is also hidden. I don't think it's the sidebars.

Comment: @Boris your js sets the width and height when resizing, the % value you set are overridden. If you use firebug and set important to the 100% width and height the issue disappears

Comment: Like I said, make it reset the width/height to 100% on window resize. When javascript is disabled the problem doesnt occur

Comment: You say you're using 'this javascript' but I don't see any code in your question. WHich Javascript are you referring to?

Comment: @DA. Thanks. But I've already worked it out. Can't delete it. And I have to wait 2 days to accept my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By removing all the height and width variables, I was able to keep the script from modifying my css.
Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In your class .wrapper, mask and itens* try using % values. This works for me!

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So I'm trying to inspect all yours elements and i notice if you change with property to 100% your animation works good! Instead of the "back div" coming from right is coming from bottom

This is a advice -> If u use 'px' unit you will have serious problem just because your web app isn't **responsive**!

See the transition with 100% width except the frist one and notice the white border appears!

[image: transition]

You need to figure out what its better for you

[image: see image whiteout px values!!]

If you really need the "back div" coming from right you need to do a transition and using 'margins' and 'z-index'

Comment: .item is tied with the animation. Changing the width value, affects the animations. I don't believe the problem is css related. Has to do with the javascript. Just can't seem to figure out what exactly.

Comment: @Boris well this seems to be the actual problem for me too. without posting your proper css and js i doubt whether someone can find the issue more accurately.

Comment: @TilwinJoy The css and javascript are in the document. And I've also listed the source where I got the script from.

Comment: @Boris Well personally i wouldn't bother to dig it out from a document or so :|